# Obtener maximo en un array object PHP

Tags: javascript, php, array

Tengo una siguiente código en `JS` donde creo un array de objetos con cantidades y obtener el mayor cantidad y sacar el código de ese.

Me gustaría la forma de hacerlo en `PHP`

Para recorrer la tabla de lineas y actualizar la tabla principal.

```
  $query_principal = "SELECT * FROM tbl_principal";
  $result       = mysqli_query($ConexionMYSQL, $query_principal);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $orden = $row['orden'];
           $data[] = array(); /*Array para guardar datos*/
           $query_line = "SELECT * FROM tbl_lineas WHERE orden = '$orden'";
           $result_line       = mysqli_query($ConexionMYSQL, $query_line);
            while ($roww = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_line)) {

              array_push($data, array(
                  "cantidad" => $roww['cantidad'],
                  "codigo" => $roww['codigo'],
              ));
            }
            /*Saber cual tiene mayor cantidad y obtener codigo*/
            // $maximo  = array_reduce($data, function ($previous, $current) {
            //    return ($previous['cantidad'] > $current['cantidad']) ? $previous : $current;
            // });

            // echo $maximo['codigo'];
            
          }
```

Codigo en JS

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var array_data = [];

  array_data.push({
    "codigo": '1',
    "cantidad": '2',
    "code": '001',
  });

  array_data.push({
    "codigo": '2',
    "cantidad": '7',
    "code": '002',
  });

  const max = array_data.reduce(function(prev, current) {
    return (prev.cantidad > current.cantidad) ? prev : current
  });
  
  console.log(max.code);

});
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Si quieres obtener el mayor podrías usar `SELECT MAX ...` por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Php tiene las mismas funciones para realizar la misma operación, se llama array_reduce y funciona igual a como funciona en javascript , el equivalente sería de  la siguiente manera.

```
$data = [];

            
array_push($data,array ("codigo" => "1",
            "cantidad" => "2",
            "code" => "001"));
            
array_push($data,array ("codigo" => "2",
            "cantidad" => "7",
            "code" => "002"));


$result = array_reduce($data, function($prev,$current){
    return  ((int)$prev["cantidad"] > (int)$current["cantidad"]) ? $prev : $current;
});

echo $result["code"];
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Me muestra el siguiente error en mi PHP log `PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /workspace/Main.php on line 15`

Comment: Si, ese error se puede dar en distintas versiones , dependiendo qué tipo de errores estés mostrando, en realidad solo es un warning pero se soluciona de esta manera :    return  (isset($prev["cantidad"]) && ((int)$prev["cantidad"] > (int)$current["cantidad"])) ? $prev : $current;